# Ruby on Rails - Error 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I have a client who runs ruby on rails and unfortunately i'm not 100% o fay with Ruby... Anyway today their site keeps returning error 500 when browsing to the site.

Looking at the error_log all I can see is the following:

```
[ 2015-11-16 20:16:45.5125 11424/7fcdb8049700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /home/rails/production started on PID 22379, listening on unix:/tmp/p$
App 22504 stdout:
App 22950 stdout:
App 22950 stderr: /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: already initialized constant SMTPSession
App 22950 stderr: /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687: warning: already initialized constant POP
App 22950 stderr: /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688: warning: already initialized constant POPSession
App 22950 stderr: /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689: warning: already initialized constant POP3Session
App 22950 stderr: /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: already initialized constant APOPSession
App 22950 stdout: MultiParameterHack loaded
App 22950 stderr: [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set$
[ 2015-11-16 20:33:27.7232 11424/7fcdb9f61700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:298 ]: Preloader for /home/rails/production started on PID 22950, listening on unix:/tmp/p$
App 23101 stdout:
```

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

I can also see this within the production.log:

```
Rendered shared/_meganav.html.erb (86.0ms)
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (197.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 278ms
** [Airbrake] Success: Net::HTTPOK
** [Airbrake] Environment Info: [Ruby: 1.9.3] [Rails: 3.0.19] [Env: production]
** [Airbrake] Response from Airbrake:
UUID: 1555278126118213905
URL:  https://airbrake.io/locate/1555278126118213905

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `has_image?' for nil:NilClass):
    269:                           <% event = Event.featured.newest.first %>
    270:
    271:              <article class="featured-event">
    272:                <% if event.has_image? %>
    273:                <div class="image"><span></span><%= link_to(image_tag(event.image.expiring_url(:featured)), event_path(event)) %></div>
    274:                <% end %>
    275:                  <div class="text">
  app/views/shared/_meganav.html.erb:272:in `_app_views_shared__meganav_html_erb__3450254428998327647_59198060__3999436880091196355'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:223:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1905251585106566541_49797400_3662579409495417543'
```

Comment: Apparently not a relevant section of logs. We need more data.

Comment: Hey @KarlWilbur thanks for reply. Which logs should I take a look at?

Comment: It depends on the app and configuration. Maybe `log/production.log`. What web server is used? The web server's error log might be helpful too.

Comment: @KarlWilbur the errors above were from the server log /var/log/error_log

Comment: I'll a look at the other one now.

Comment: @KarlWilbur i've updated with the application.log

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your issue is that there is no `Event` that matches `featured.newest`, which means that `event` is nil. As `nil#has_image?` is not an available method, a NoMethodError is thrown and you end up seeing a 500 error on the server.

The Event query belongs in your controller, and your output should have a nil-guard to ensure this doesn't happen. For example:

```
# app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
def index
  @event = Event.featured.newest.first
end

# app/views/pages/home.html.erb
<% if @event.present? %>
  <article class="featured-event">
  ...
  </article>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi coreyward thanks for this man, sorry I have never used ruby...

Do I just need to add <% if @event.present? %> before the <% if event.has_image?%>?

Comment: Depending on your application needs, you might be able to do this in your controller: `@event = Event.featured.newest.first || Event.new`.

Comment: I've made that change but still getting the same error? Do i need to recompile anything?

Answer (score 1):

Change `<% if event.has_image? %>` to:

```
<% if event && event.has_image? %>
```

...or in Ruby >= 2.3

```
<% if event&.has_image? %>
```